# R ggplot legend giving decimals when I want whole numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am creating a bubble plot and all of my values are whole numbers. However, when the code is run, the legend scale gives me decimals (i.e. 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10).  I want it to be whole numbers like 2,5,8,11.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot() +
geom_path(data = usa, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
theme_general + geom_point(data = CombinedStudentsUSA1, 
aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = Number), color = "blue", shape=19, alpha=.5)+
scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 4))
```

I have made multiple versions of this plot and all of them default to a whole number scale. For some reason, this specific version of the data does not do that. Help?

Comment: Specify breaks you like?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Sorry, I'm very new with R coding.  This is what my data looks like. X axis is longitude values, y-axis is latitude values, and my z-axis (group) is population/group size. That is what the legend is showing.  I would want the legend to do values of 2, 5, 8, and 11 if possible. 

http://i62.tinypic.com/2yn1gl5.png

Comment: `scale_size_continuous` offers a `breaks` argument, which allows you specifying exactly the breaks you want.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks! That worked.  Here's what I ended up with as my final code:

```
ggplot() +
geom_path(data = usa, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + theme_general +
geom_point(data = CombinedStudentsUSA1, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = Number),     
color = "blue", shape=19, alpha=.5)+ scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 4),  
breaks= c(2,4,6,8), name="Number of \nResponses")
```

http://i57.tinypic.com/291jfcl.jpg

[image]